# Fail to display SVG image in tizen

Tags: image, svg, tizen

When trying to display an SVG image i get a black screen, when replacing the image with png i can see the image in the watch screen.
I tried few different images...
this is the code i used:

```
char buf[250];
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%s/Firefox_Logo.svg", app_get_resource_path());
/* Return Evas handle from window */
Evas *e = evas_object_evas_get(ad->conform);
/* Create an image object */
Evas_Object *img = evas_object_image_add(e);
/* Set a source file to fetch pixel data */
evas_object_image_file_set(img,buf, NULL);
/* Set the size and position of the image on the image object area */
evas_object_image_fill_set(img, 0, 0, 300, 300);

evas_object_move(img, 0, 0);
evas_object_resize(img, 300, 300);
evas_object_show(img);
```

Comment: the code for presenting the image was take from here: https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/guides/native-application/user-interface/efl/primitive-graphical-objects/evas-objects?langredirect=1

Answer (score 0):

As there's no sample code snippet in the reference link you've shared I would like to suggest you to use [Dynamic Animation Library (DALi)](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/guides/native-application/user-interface/dali?langredirect=1).

You can render an SVG image on screen with DALi with both C++ and JSON. Please follow [this link](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/guides/native-application/user-interface/dali/rendering-and-effects/svg-rendering?langredirect=1) to know more detail.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, My app is written in EFL so displaying an SVG image using DALi will require changing the whole app interface to DALi as far as i understand. As for tizen documentation in the link i provided EFL image supports SVG and there is a code snippet (same as i provided) that works with jpg but not with SVG